# Concatenat a column in a Dataset with a Value Spark Java API

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

I want to concatenate the column in my DataSet with $ value.

My DataSet is like this.

```
+---------+-------------------+
    |C1       |       C2          |
    +---------+-------------------+
    |   448631|           -2219.13|
    |   444000|          -12546.84|
    |   411000|           186719.0|
```

I want to obtain something like this:

```
+---------+-------------------   +
|C1       |       C2             |
+---------+-------------------   +
|   448631 $|          -2219.13 $|
|   444000 $|         -12546.84 $|
|   411000 $|          186719.0 $|
```

Somebody can guide me with a simple expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can create new columns based on the old ones and then drop the old ones. The following is a Python implementation:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
...
originalDF = spark.createDataFrame([(111, 222), (333, 444), (555, 666)], ['C1', 'C2'])
originalDF.show()

expectedDF = originalDF.withColumn('NewC1', F.concat(F.col('C1'), F.lit(' $')))\
    .withColumn('NewC2', F.concat(F.col('C2'), F.lit(' $')))\
    .drop(F.col('C1'))\
    .drop(F.col('C2'))
expectedDF.show()
```

Original DataFrame:

```
+---+---+
| C1| C2|
+---+---+
|111|222|
|333|444|
|555|666|
+---+---+
```

Expected DataFrame:

```
+-----+-----+
|NewC1|NewC2|
+-----+-----+
|111 $|222 $|
|333 $|444 $|
|555 $|666 $|
+-----+-----+
```